# Why is Core Plot delegate protocol not found?

Tags: objective-c, core-plot

I try to use [Rays](http://www.raywenderlich.com/13271/how-to-draw-graphs-with-core-plot-part-2) tutorial of Core plot for my iPad App 
I use a SplitViewController
And I want to have a scatter plot in my DetailViewController

I change my Code to:

```
@interface GWDetailViewController : UIViewController <UISplitViewControllerDelegate,CPTPlotDataSource>
```

and now I get this error:

> Cannot find protocol declaration for 'CPTPlotDataSource'

to add frameworks and librarys was no problem
[image: screenshot from my project]

What is wrong?

Comment: `#import <TheHeaderFileThatContainsTheProtocolDeclaration.h>`

Comment: thank you, that helped
but, in the example from ray there is no #import
I try to understand why...

Comment: No problem whatsoever, I'd just suggest that you go back a bit to the basics of Objective-C to learn them and know them fluently.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the .h file for your view controller contains the following import statement:

```
#import "CorePlot-CocoaTouch.h"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to import header file every time, you can Import it in .pch file for once.

In your scenario ,Open .pch file(usually placed in supporting file folder ) and add following code.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "CorePlot-CocoaTouch.h"
#import "CPDConstants.h"
#import "CPDStockPriceStore.h"
```